# mostrar detalle del producto al darle click

Tags: angularjs, ionic

Buenas noches amigos, estoy realizando un carrito de compras en ionic y quiero mostrar el detalle de cada producto en un modal al momento de darle click sobre su imagen.

Este es el código que me muestra todos los productos

```
  <div ng-repeat="p in producto  |filter:buscador" ng-model="checked">
  <a href="#/detalle?idp={{ p.id }}">
    <div  class="contenedorP text-center" ng-init="checked=0" style="width: 33.3333333333%; float: left;">

      <img src="{{p.picture}}" class="itemProducto"  width="100" height="110" alt="">
      <p class=" pullDown  precio">{{ p.name }} </p>  
      <p class=" pullDown  precio">{{ p.price |  currency: "$" : 0 }} </p>               
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Quiero realizar un método que al darle click me muestre un modal con el detalle de ese producto y me muestre la opcion de agregar o no al carrito

[image: ejemplo]

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44843/discussion-on-question-by-francisco-jose-rodriguez-diaz-mostrar-detalle-del-prod).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sólo tienes que invocar al servicio `$ionicModal` desde el controller. Eso no es algo que puedas hacer desde la vista así que tienes que usar un método y `ng-click`

```
<div ng-repeat="p in producto  |filter:buscador" ng-model="checked">
  <a ng-click="showDetails(p)">
    <div  class="contenedorP text-center" ng-init="checked=0" style="width: 33.3333333333%; float: left;">

      <img src="{{p.picture}}" class="itemProducto"  width="100" height="110" alt="">
      <p class=" pullDown  precio">{{ p.name }} </p>  
      <p class=" pullDown  precio">{{ p.price |  currency: "$" : 0 }} </p>               
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Tienes que crear un HTML o una plantilla para el modal con los datos necesarios para mostrar los detalles (aquí solo pongo lo que tienes como ejemplo)

**modal-details.html**

```
<img src="{{current.picture}}" class="itemProducto"  width="100" height="110" alt="">
<p class="pullDown  precio">{{ current.name }} </p>  
<p class="pullDown  precio">{{ current.price |  currency: "$" : 0 }} </p>
```

y en el controller

```
$scope.showDetails = function(product) {
    $scope.current = product;

    $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('modal-details.html', {
        scope: $scope,
        animation: 'slide-in-up'
    }).then(function(modal) {
        $scope.modal = modal;
    });
}
```

El truco es usar una propiedad del `$scope` para señalizar cual es el producto seleccionado actual, yo usé `current`, tu puedes usar la que quieras ya que el modal requiere que le pases un `$scope` de referencia para su contenido, usualmente se usa el mismo del controller.

Comment: amigo no me abre el modal estoy metiendo lo dentro de un controller y no abre no se que estoy haciendo mal

Comment: @FranciscoJoseRodriguezDiaz Revisa la consola a ver que errores te da y verifica que hayas inyectado la dependencia a `$ionicModal`

Comment: no me muestra ningun error simplemente no me abre el modal y si tengo la dependencia